# Stability of discrete non-linear dynamical system with dominant eigenvalue equal to $1$

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, stability-theory

Suppose that $F :\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth map with a fixed point $e \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and that the Jacobian $J_e(F)$ of $F$ at $e$ has three distinct real eigenvalues, two of which are in the open interval $(0 , 1)$ and the third **equal** to $1$.

I have [read](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Scientific_Computing_Simulations_and_Modeling/Book%3A_Introduction_to_the_Modeling_and_Analysis_of_Complex_Systems_(Sayama)/05%3A_DiscreteTime_Models_II__Analysis/5.07%3A_5.7_Linear_Stability_Analysis_of_Discrete-Time_Nonlinear_Dynamical_Systems) that in this situation it is *possible* that the resulting non-linear discrete dynamical system is Lyapunov stable, but this reference states that proving this requires "more advanced nonlinear analysis, which is beyond the scope of this textbook".

What methods are there to assess the Lyapunov (or any other kind of) stability of such a dynamical system?

Can anyone point me in the direction of some references that contain this type of stability theory, specifically in the non-linear case?

Comment: The point of the statement is that the dynamical system doesn't have to behave like its linearization at that fixed point. The linearization will just decay the other modes and preserve the mode in the direction of that third eigenvector. The actual system can do any number of things instead. So coming to grips with the stability requires "getting into the weeds" of how the system behaves near the fixed point, with case-specific estimates and so forth.

Comment: (Cont.) You can try to do the same kind of Taylor's theorem work for instance, but you'll need to examine the higher order terms to be assured of anything.

Comment: @Ian - Ah that's very helpful! Thank you! Any chance you have a reference for this kind of stuff (e.g. using the higher-order terms of the Taylor series to asses stability)?